# Unable to push messages on to Kafka topic deployed in a docker container from another docker container

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

In the windows machine, I have created a Kafka container which is up and running. I am able to post messages on to the Kafka topic by using the below producer java code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Assign topicName to string variable
        String topicName = "ms-txnclassification-inbox-topic";

        // create instance for properties to access producer configs
        Properties props = new Properties();

        // Assign localhost id
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "kafka:29092");

        // Set acknowledgements for producer requests.
        props.put("acks", "all");

        // If the request fails, the producer can automatically retry,
        props.put("retries", 1);

        // Specify buffer size in config
        props.put("batch.size", 16384);

        // Reduce the no of requests less than 0
        props.put("linger.ms", 1);

        // The buffer.memory controls the total amount of memory available to the
        // producer for buffering.
        props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);

        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        
        try (KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer(props)){
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            try {
                ProducerRecord<String, String> message1 = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, Integer.toString(100), Integer.toString(100));
                producer.send(message1);
                System.out.println("Value sent " + i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to deliver message");
        }
        System.out.println("Message sent successfully");

    }
```

At the same time which I package this code into a jar file and deploy it into a container, I am unable to post the messages on to the same Kafka topic. Surprisingly the code also does not throw any error or exception.

Dockerfile which I have created for the container from where I am posting the messages:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
COPY KafkaTopicTest.jar /app/KafkaTopicTest.jar
```

Once this docker container is up and running I run the jar file manually.

```
java -jar KafkaTopicTest.jar com.temenos.transactionClassificationExecutable.loadTesting.ProducerTesting
```

Note: When I ping kafka within the container I am getting a successful response.

```
# ping kafka
PING kafka (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
^C
--- kafka ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2113ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.042/0.065/0.079/0.016 ms
#
```

Not sure where I am going wrong!!

Comment: Looks like you are pinging kafka from itself, not another container. Not sure what that is supposed to show... What do you mean "run the JAR manually"?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you test the code locally? If so, `kafka:29092` shouldn't work, but `localhost:29092` might, depending on your Kafka configuration and port mappings...

From what you've shown, your Dockerfile is going to exit after running without some CMD or ENTRYPOINT that runs the JAR, so if you're doing `docker run -ti <image> bash`, then running the JAR, I see no reason why it shouldn't work (although, I think you should flush the producer manually)

If "run the JAR file manually" means you are doing `docker build`, a non-interative docker run, then immediately `java -jar`, then you're still in Windows, and running the JAR from there, and thus `kafka:29092` is not resolvable, as mentioned.

Your code also probably doesn't return any error about producing because it needs to call `producer.flush()` since 2 messages is not enough to create a batch. Add a finally block to do this, unless you expect the try-with-resources to call that for you.

Then, additionally, if you're not using Docker Compose, then you must define a shared network for the containers to communicate over

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes, I am running the docker file locally, kafka:29092 works as I have defined kafka in hosts file of the windows system.

Comment: As suggested, I even have added producer.flush() and it still does not work.

Comment: If you'd setup the advertised listeners of the container, you shouldn't edit the hosts file. Regardless, you've not shown the containers are part of the same network